# Android Custom KeyBoardView clear default keys

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view, android-keypad

I have custom MyKBV class which extends KeyBoardView.I created this custom view to use custom font for the keys. I am able to see the changed font on the keys but the problem is each key overlap's with the default keys from the XML which I presume is TypefaceE.DEFAULT_BOLD.SO what I am seeing is two strings on each key one bold and one with the font I want.How do I go about clearing the default keys so that only the custom ones are visible.I have spent a lot of time on this .It would be helpful if someone can point out where I am going wrong or what I could do.Thanks!!

```
public class MyKBV extends KeyboardView {
Context context;

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "fonts/Hippie.otf");
    paint.setTypeface(font);
    paint.setTextSize(40);

    List<Key> listKeys = getKeyboard().getKeys();

    for (Key key : listKeys) {
        if (key.label != null) {
            if (key.label.toString().length() > 1) {
                paint.setTextSize(30);
                canvas.drawText(key.label.toString(), key.x
                        + (key.width / 2) - 15, key.y + (key.height / 2)
                        + 10, paint);
            } else {
                canvas.drawText(key.label.toString(), key.x
                        + (key.width / 2) - 10, key.y + (key.height / 2)
                        + 10, paint);
            }
        }
    }

}

public MyKeyBoardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;

}
```

}

Comment: Um, have you tried not calling super.onDraw? That will prevent the underlying keyboard from drawing itself.. assuming you want to do all the drawing yourself..

Comment: have u found any solution @luckysing

Answer (score 0):

If you override the onDraw() you should draw background first then draw your text.

```
public class MyKeyboardView extends android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView {

    Context context;
    public MyKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context ;
    }



    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

         Paint paint = new Paint();
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "fonts/Hippie.otf");
    paint.setTypeface(font);
    paint.setTextSize(40);




        List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
        for(Key key: keys) {

     if(key.pressed){
                NinePatchDrawable npd = (NinePatchDrawable)context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.glow);
                npd.setBounds(key.x,key.y,key.x+key.width,key.y+key.height);
                npd.draw(canvas);
            if(key.label != null)
                canvas.drawText(key.label.toString(), key.x + (key.width/2), key.y + 25, paint);
     }else if(key.modifier){  // boolean that defines key is function key

            NinePatchDrawable npd = (NinePatchDrawable)context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_keyboard_special);
            npd.setBounds(key.x,key.y,key.x+key.width,key.y+key.height);
            npd.draw(canvas);
            if(key.label != null)
                canvas.drawText(key.label.toString(), key.x + (key.width/2), key.y + 25, paint);
      }


        break;
        }
    }
```